# ZipInputStream and DigestInputStream doesn't work together

Tags: java, md5, zipinputstream

When I trying to calculate on the fly the MD5 of a zip file and unzip it at the same time, for some zip file it doesn't work: the MD5 sum is incorrect although the file is not corrupted.

Here a snippet of my code:

```
MessageDigest lMd = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

FileOutputStream lFos = null;
try (DigestInputStream lDis = new DigestInputStream(lListener.getInputStream(), lMd);
                            ZipInputStream lZip = new ZipInputStream(lDis)) {

    // Read the response content
    //get the zipped file list entry
    ZipEntry lZipEntry = lZip.getNextEntry();

    while (lZipEntry != null) {
        String lFileName = lZipEntry.getName();

        File lNewFile = new File(UPDATE_FOLDER + File.separator + lFileName);

        if (lZipEntry.isDirectory()) {
            lNewFile.mkdirs();
        } else {
            //create all non exists folders
            new File(lNewFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

            lFos = new FileOutputStream(lNewFile);             

            int lRead;
            while ((lRead = lZip.read(lBuffer)) > -1) {
                lFos.write(lBuffer, 0, lRead);
            }

            lFos.close();   
        }

        lZipEntry = lZip.getNextEntry();
    }

    lZip.closeEntry();
} finally {
    if (lFos != null) {
        lFos.close();
}
                        byte[] lDigest = lMd.digest();

                    StringBuffer lHexString = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int lI = 0; lI < lDigest.length; lI++) {
                        if ((0xFF & lDigest[lI]) < 0x10) {
                            lHexString.append("0"
                                    + Integer.toHexString((0xFF & lDigest[lI])));
                        } else {
                            lHexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & lDigest[lI]));
                        }
                    }
                    String lDigestStr = lHexString.toString();
```

Can you help me?

Thank you!
aGO!

Comment: Why are you declaring `FileOutputStream lFos` outside? You know how to use try-with-resources, so use it on `new FileOutputStream`.

Comment: `lZip.closeEntry()` is meaningless. At least it is where you have it now.

Comment: Since you like assignment-in-while-loop for your inner loop, why not the outer loop?

Comment: As for your real question, you don't show the code that uses the digest. Your issue might be there.

Comment: The problem is on DigestInputStream that when I do lMd.digest() the digest is wrong.

Comment: I updated the snippet

Comment: Use `StringBuilder`, not `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any issues. Are you comparing MD5 to the value from the `md5sum` command-line?

Comment: Yes. It seams when the zip is flat (no folder) it works. If the zip has folder, it doen't work

Comment: You should probably stop doing it like that. I mean, you really should verify the MD5 *before* using it, right? Maybe that'll work for you, and is more correct too.

Comment: I need verify the Md5 before using it. A workaraund should be calulate the Md5 on the file before unzipping it

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the two operations. `ZipInputStream` is not built to fully consume an underlying stream. The reason for this is the ZIP file format which basically looks like this:

```
<file header><file data>
<file header><file data>
<file header><file data>
<...>
<last file header><last file data>
<directory header>
<directory header>
<directory header>
<...>
<last directory header>
```

`<file header>` and `<directory header>` have different signatures. Here’s what `ZipInputStream` does when `getNextEntry()` is called:

```
if (get32(tmpbuf, 0) != LOCSIG) {
    return null;
}
```

It verifies that the buffer it has just read starts with the characters “PK\003\004” which would be a correct file header. However, once the directory headers start, this will start returning `null` because directory headers are “PK\001\002.”

After this the `ZipInputStream` will return `null` from `getNextEntry()` after which you will stop consuming it. The only solution for your particular problem would be to first verify the file, then unpacking it. As mentioned in the comments you should do it that way anyway because you should definitely *not* use the file if the verification failed!